# [UWP][MVVM] Navigate in a frame in a window

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I'm building an UWP app with a navigationview. When I click on my navigation item I want to change my frame. It's really easy to do this without MVVM but I prefer a solution with MVVM.

[image]

My Frame is "ContentFrame". Now I want to use a navigationservice. 
The classic way to do this is:

```
 public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    public void NavigateTo(Type viewType)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(viewType);
    }

    public void NavigateBack()
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

But for my use case the "Window.Current.Content" should be replaced with the Frame from my HomePage. I've no idea how I can access this through MVVM.

My project is on a public git: https://github.com/stefmorren/AutoClicker/tree/Devel

You can do a push request if it's easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add a public property of type `Frame` to your `HomePage`:

```cs
public Frame NavigationFrame => ContentFrame;
```

Now, your `HomePage` is currently inside a root `Frame`. To get to it, you will have to use it's `Content` property:

```cs
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    public void NavigateTo(Type viewType)
    {
        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var homePage = rootFrame.Content as HomePage;
        homePage.NavigationFrame.Navigate(viewType);
    }

    public void NavigateBack()
    {
        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var homePage = rootFrame.Content as HomePage;
        homePage.NavigationFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

### Even simpler solution

To simplify this a bit more, you could even remove the `rootFrame` altogether. In `App.xaml.cs` you have to update your code to create the `HomePage` directly:

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    HomePage page = Window.Current.Content as HomePage;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (page == null)
    {
        page = new HomePage();
        Window.Current.Content = page;
    }

    if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
    {
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

And you would now use the following to access the `NavigationFrame` property:

```cs
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    public void NavigateTo(Type viewType)
    {
        var homePage = Window.Current.Content as HomePage;
        homePage.NavigationFrame.Navigate(viewType);
    }

    public void NavigateBack()
    {
        var homePage = Window.Current.Content as HomePage;
        homePage.NavigationFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Now `HomePage` is directly the `Content` of your `Window`, so we can access it via `Window.Current.Content`.

Comment: Thanks! Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding :-)

Comment: Here is my solution https://github.com/KWodarczyk/UwpWinUI3PageMVVMNavigation

Comment: But if this solution is a MVVM solution? I just thinking about one thing, what will be if for example each navigated content should to have his own `DataContext`?